# Is it possible to export a sub set of symbols using gcc?

Tags: linux, gcc, compilation

I have an executable now. And I want to call some functions in this executable from other process, so I try to compile the executable using "-fPIC -pie -rdynamic", and usig dlopen() dlsym() to call the functions. It works as expected. But "-rdynamic" exports many symbols which is not needed. I only want to export a sub set of them. How to do it?

Comment: Is your shared object a wrapper shared object using [Visibility](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Visibility)? If not, start using symbol visibility. If so, build it with `-Wl,--exclude-libs,ALL`. It stops your shared object from re-exporting other library symbols.

Comment: You could use libtool, it has an option `-export-symbols` that takes a file containg a list of symbol-names.

Comment: I have found a solution. Using -Wl,--dynamic-list,symbol.list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a solution. Using -Wl,--dynamic-list,symbol.list 
symbol.list is a file in current path, with content like:

```
{foo;goo;};
```

which means that I export symbol foo and goo